# Is there something like CodeRush from Java?

Tags: java, coderush

Is there something like [CodeRush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeRush) for Java?

Comment: Is there a specific Java IDE that you're using?

Comment: Codeush is a productivity tool for Microsoft Visual studio - http://devexpress.com/CodeRush or http://devexpress.com/crx or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeRush

Answer (score 4):

The real answer is that Many Java IDE's give the same types of features (as relevant for Java), so you should really check them out and then ask about a specific missing feature that you had in CodeRush that you think would be relevant to a Java IDE.

Comment: This is true, coming from a Java background (Eclipse mostly), I was baffled at how few navigational features the Visual Studio code editor offers out of the box. Much of what CodeRush / Resharper bring to Visual Studio is an out of the box feature in all three of the major Java IDE's.

Answer (score 4):

While not quite like CodeRush, you can try JetBrains IDE for java (IntelliJ) to get similar functionality to what Resharper offers (not that dissimilar to CodeRush)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing exist that is exactly like CodeRush for Java. The closest thing you will find is the JetBrains IDE as [saret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1940956/25882) said.

The design philosophy of CodeRush/Refactor! is to never show a modal dialog like Eclipse/Resharper/Visual Studio does for refactoring. Instead CodeRush uses context sensitivity, by watching the AST, and only shows you refactorings that make sense. CodeRush/Refactor draws on top of the editor and animates things where appropriate.

Animation example:
[image]

Image source: http://www.skorkin.com/2012/07/reordering-method-parameters-with-visual-studio-and-coderush/